# Calling a web service to obtain an byte[] in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I've writing a application on Android which calls a .Net restful wcf web service I've written.  I'm successfully obtaining XML and String results, but cannot call a method on the web service which returns a byte[] - it looks like its encoding is alerted.

I am using the org.apache.http.HttpHost library and an currently reading the byte[] as a string (the encoding in eclipse looks like unicode);

```
     InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            str.append(line);
        }

        in.close();
        String asciiString = str.toString();
```

Basically I want to convert the data held in asciiString to a Bitmap (the WCF service outputs a byte[] of a PNG image)

If anyone can offer pointers as what I am doing wrong or how to do this (if it is possible) it would be most welcome.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I don't have an IDE installed here, but here's how I think it should go: open a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, to which you write byte by byte (or better, buffering in some way, of course) what you read from your `InputStream in`. To obtain your `byte[]` use the method `toByteArray()`.

Comment: Thanks.  Done this, and discovered the issue is with the byte[] being encoded using application/json.  THis is done by the .Net WCF service and can been seen by browsing the Url;

Comment: http://aspspider.org/lonesheep/RestServiceImpl.svc/getimagebinary/69332dea-3a2d-41a6-ba07-ae319780b7cb

Comment: any ideas how I convert this result to a byte[] so I can read the png file which is returned?  or do I need to return the image byte